# Why does "the then chairman" contain "the then" at the same time?

Tags: prepositions, word-meaning, past-tense, adjectives

> A special court for CBI cases on Monday framed charges against **the then** chairman and managing director, executive director and senior vice-president of the erstwhile Global Trust Bank and representatives of a private firm in connection with a multi-crore scam.

Why is 'the then' used at the same time, and what does that mean?

Comment: "The then chairman" means the chairman at the time (not the current chairman). The preposition *then* refers to an earlier time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider the similar example

> I wanted to live in the city, but my *then* husband (= the man who was my husband at that time) preferred the country.

*Then* (before a noun) is an adjective and means *at that time*.

Comment: Is there meant to be hyphenation?